# Treat index.html as default file in Akka HTTP's getFromDirectory

Tags: scala, akka-http

Assuming I have a folder `foo` with an `index.html` file in it and the following minimal (but most likely not functional) server code for Akka HTTP below:

```
object Server extends App {
  val route: Route =
    pathPrefix("foo") {
      getFromDirectory("foo")
    }

  Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 8080)
}
```

`index.html` will correctly be served if I open `http://localhost:8080/foo/index.html` in a browser, but not if I open `http://localhost:8080/foo` or `http://localhost:8080/foo/`.

**If this is even possible, how can I set up my Akka HTTP routes to serve `index.html` files within that location by default?**

I know I could do the following:

```
val route: Route =
  path("foo") {
     getFromFile("foo/index.html")
  } ~
  pathPrefix("foo") {
    getFromDirectory("foo")
  }
```

But:

- This only makes `http://localhost:8080/foo` work, not `http://localhost:8080/foo/`
- This is very ad-hoc and does not apply globally: if I have a `foo/bar/index.html` file, the problem will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the `Route` you are looking for by using the `pathEndOrSingleSlash` Directive:

```
val route =
  pathPrefix("foo") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      getFromFile("foo/index.html")
    } ~ 
    getFromDirectory("foo")
  }
```

This Route  will match at the end of the path and feed up the index.html, or if the end doesn't match it will call getFromDirectory instead.

If you want to make this "global" you can make a function out of it:

```
def routeAsDir[T](pathMatcher : PathMatcher[T], dir : String) : Route = 
  pathPrefix(pathMatcher) {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      getFromFile(dir + "/index.html")
    } ~ 
    getFromDirectory(dir)
  }
```

This can then be called with

```
val barRoute = routeAsDir("foo" / "bar", "foo/bar")
```

**Functional Akka Http**

Side note: your code is completely functional.  The elegance of the Directives DSL can be a bit misleading and convince you that you've accidentally strayed back into imperative programming style.  But each of the Directives is simply a function; can't get more "functional" than that...