# How do you use PathMatcher with pathPrefix to redirect a path url to /index.html in akka-http 10?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm using akka-http 10.0.10, and have the following file (I extracted it to single file to narrow down imports slightly, but the issue is the same):

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.server._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._

object RouteHelpers {

  def indexRoute(dir : String): Route =
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      getFromFile(dir + "/index.html")
    } ~
    getFromDirectory(dir)

  def routeAsDir[T](pathMatcher : PathMatcher[T], dir : String) : Route =
    pathPrefix(pathMatcher)(indexRoute(dir))
}
```

This results in the error:

```
RouteHelpers.scala:15:28: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[T] does not take parameters
[error]     pathPrefix(pathMatcher)(indexRoute(dir))
```

Original ref for this is https://stackoverflow.com/a/42886042/3096687.

Comment: What is the `pathMatcher : PathMatcher[T]` ? If it is a `PathMatcher0` that works. If it is a `PathMatcher1[T]` that would also work but you'd have to extract the matching field like

`def routeAsDir[T](pathMatcher : PathMatcher1[T], dir : String) : Route = pathPrefix(pathMatcher){field => indexRoute(dir)}`

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason behind this error is because of the magnet pattern.If you use `pathPrefix(pathMatcher)(indxRoute(dir))` then the `(indxRoute(dir))` block is mistaken as the implicit argument of `pathPrefix`. `pathPrefix` returns a directive of type `Directive[T]` and `Directive` class does not take any implicit parameters and hence the error.

The possible solutions could be:

### using `tapply` method

`tapply` method is a special method present in `Directive` class. `tapply` calls the inner route with a tuple of extracted values of type `T` as shown in below sample of code:

```
def routeAsDir[T](pathMatcher: PathMatcher[T], dir: String): Route = {
  pathPrefix(pathMatcher).tapply(t => indexRoute(dir))
}
```

### Alternative Approach

```
def routeAsDir[T](pathMatcher: PathMatcher[T]): Directive[T] = pathPrefix(pathMatcher)
```

Use this function to get Directive and use this directive to construct route as shown below:

```
val matcher: PathMatcher[Unit] = "foo" / "bar"
val route: Route = routeAsDir(matcher) {
    indexRoute("foo/bar")
}
```

This solution works because `routeAsDir(matcher)` returns `Directive[Unit]` or `Directive0` to which the apply method is called with the inner routes.

Let me know if this helps!